Tikz template for organization chart
I am trying to create an organizational chart but am having trouble formatting it in a suitable way. Below is the initial version I have created:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance = 0.4cm, thick,
  every node/.style = {rectangle, font = \sffamily, white,
    top color = blue!80!white, bottom color = blue!50!white,
    text width = 2.4cm, align = center, minimum height = 1cm}]
  \node (GF)                                 {\textbf{GF}\\Geschäftsführer};
  \coordinate [below = 0.5cm of GF] (hass);
  \coordinate [below = 1.8cm of GF] (al);
  \coordinate [below = 3.1cm of GF] (hos);
  \coordinate [below = 4.4cm of GF] (ghas);
  \node (Verwaltung) [below = of hass]  {Verwaltung /\\ Büro};
  \node (EDV)        [below = of al]  {EDV \& QS};
  \node (Bau)        [below = of hos] {Bau};
  \node (Logistik)   [left  = of Bau]        {Logistik};
  \node (Ausbildung) [right = of Bau]     {Ausbildung};
  \node (Pflege)     [below = of ghas]        {Pflege};
  \draw [gray!60!black,thick]
    (GF)    -- (hass) -- (Verwaltung)
    (al)   -- (EDV);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Could anyone help me create a well-organized chart, which might also be useful for others in the future?
Thanks,
Mo

please complete your code so people can compile it. tikzpicture is not a standard environment ;).

I think you have now the edited version.

Do you check your MWE? It contain errors ... What is wrong with your chart? It is quite OK, however, the code can be a bit shorter and more consistent ...

if I correct your code so it compiles, the chart looks OK. as @Zarko says, what's wrong with it exactly? what do you want to change? I mean, I'd draw it as a tree using forest, but that's just my preference. I'd also choose a colour scheme which made it easier for me to read, but that's just my eyes. (white-on-bright is hard on screen.)

I can't make the lines between the boxes connected, and the boxes totally don't look well-shaped.

ok, so they can be connected. but what shape should they be?

connecting all the boxes in a row and the ones in the columns to their neighbours.

A screenshot of your codes result, and a sketch of what it should look like, may clarify things more easily. Thanks

It is not entirely clear, what you expected from suggested solution. I guess that something like this:

The code for above chart use chains library for placement of nodes in the main (middle) chain of nodes (why distance between first in second you made different from others?):
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,        % so far is not used ...
                chains,
                ext.paths.ortho,    % for -|-, |-| and r-rl path operations
                positioning,
                shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 4mm, 
  start chain = going below,
   arr/.style = {draw=gray, thick},
     N/.style = {draw, 
                 top color = blue!45!white, bottom color = blue!15!white,
                 text width = 32mm, align = center, minimum height = 11mm,
                 outer sep = 0pt
                 }
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={N, on chain, join=by arr}]
\node   {\textbf{GF}\\ Geschäftsführer};
\node   [below=12mm]    {Verwaltung /\\ Büro};
\node   (EDV)   {EDV \& QS};
\node   (Bau)   {Bau};
\node   {Pflege};
    \end{scope}
\node (Logistik)   [N, left  = of Bau]     {Logistik};
\node (Ausbildung) [N, right = of Bau]     {Ausbildung};
%  
\draw[arr]  (EDV.south) |-|  (Logistik)
            (EDV.south) |-|  (Ausbildung);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Edit:
At first I missed that you like to have white text, sans serif fonts, equal distance between nodes and arrows with some arrowhead between all nodes:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,        % so far is not used ...
                chains,
                ext.paths.ortho,    % for -|-, |-| and r-rl path operations
                positioning,
                shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 6mm and 4mm, 
  start chain = going below,
   arr/.style = {draw=gray, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, very thick}, % <---
     N/.style = {draw, 
                 top color = blue!80!white, bottom color = blue!40!white,
                 text width = 32mm, align = center, minimum height = 11mm,
                 outer sep = 0pt, font = \sffamily, text=white
                 }
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={N, on chain, join=by arr}]
\node   {\textbf{GF}\\ Geschäftsführer};
\node   {Verwaltung /\\ Büro};              % <---
\node   (EDV)   {EDV \& QS};
\node   (Bau)   {Bau};
\node   {Pflege};
    \end{scope}
\node (Logistik)   [N, left  = of Bau]     {Logistik};
\node (Ausbildung) [N, right = of Bau]     {Ausbildung};
%  
\draw[arr]  (EDV.south) |-|  (Logistik);
\draw[arr]  (EDV.south) |-|  (Ausbildung);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



@cfr, thank you for correcting my text ...

you're very welcome :-)

It is not clear what you want. I'd use forest, though it certainly isn't necessary for this. I've made a few changes to maybe help you think about what you want it to look like: rounded corners, drop shadows, a bit more vertical spacing and arrows.

\documentclass[12pt,border=5pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/727225/
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shadows}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.75cm}@{}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    font = \bfseries,
    align = C,
    font = \sffamily,
    text=white,
    top color=blue!80!white,
    bottom color=blue!50!white,
    minimum height=1cm,
    edge+={thick,-Latex},
    rounded corners,
    l sep'+=5pt,
    drop shadow,
  },
  forked edges,
  [\textbf{GF}\\Geschäftsführer
    [Verwaltung /\\ Büro
      [EDV \& QS
        [Logistik]
        [Bau
          [Ausbildung]
        ]
        [Pflege]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}


Awesome. That's exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Nice, fancy ... (+1)

@Zarko fancy, schmancy ;).
